# A function which is supposed to work on first click (in all browser possibly), is working only on the third click in Safari

Tags: javascript, function, safari, onclick, cross-browser

Everything works fine at the first click in CHROME, FIREFOX or EDGE.

Will be great if someone can explain why for Safari is not the same.

Here is the Code:

```
function ovelaly3(){
el = document.getElementById("overlay3");   
if (!el.style.visibility || el.style.visibility == "hidden") {
    el.style.visibility = "visible";
    el.style.animation= "matrix3d 0.5s linear running";        
    z.setAttribute("style", "color:#C200FF");
    } 
else {
      z.removeAttribute( "style" );
      setTimeout(animatereverse3, 0);
      setTimeout(close3, 500)
      }}

  function overlayclosed3() {
   setTimeout(animatereverse3, 0);
   setTimeout(close3, 500);
   }

  function animatereverse3(){
   el = document.getElementById("overlay3");
   el.style.animation= "matrix3d2 0.5s linear running backwards";
   }

  function close3(){
   el = document.getElementById("overlay3");
   el.style.visibility = "hidden";
   z.removeAttribute( "style" );
   }
```

Thank you for the attention :)

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: Where is your HTML and/or your code that adds the click handler?

Comment: @messerbill Hey, yes i have it, but i'm still trying to make it works. https://jsfiddle.net/ma29vanp/

Comment: @freginold i've just uploaded part of the code here https://jsfiddle.net/ma29vanp/ thx

Comment: anyone knows how to help me? :( also good references or links are welcome.